# Java: How to call a class method from an object created in the class?

Tags: java

I have a class let's say School in which I create an object Student. How would I call from Student class a method that is located in the School class without making it static?

Here's a quick example:

```
public class School(){
 Student s1 = new Student();

 public void createNewStudent(){
 Student s2 = new Student();
 }

}


public class Student(){

School.createNewStudent();

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to study OOP paradigm and Java programming first.

Comment: The example you have given doesn't make sense what you are trying to do (It won't even compile even with a static method). Anyway I also suggest you read about OOP and Java basics. You should be able to find many details even within stackoverflow itself.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of School class within your Student class

ex:

```
School school = new School();
school.createNewStudent();
```

Comment: please don't just answer, think about what he is asking before answering even if the answer seems so simple.

Answer (score 0):

In java, class method are static method.

```
public class MyClass{
  public static void myClassMethod() {
    System.out.println("inside class method");
  }

  public void myInstanceMethod() {
    MyClass.myClassMethod();
  }

  public static void main (String args[]) {
    MyClass.myClassMethod();
    MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
    myInstance.myInstanceMethod();
  }
}
```